# Equation $x^2=y^p+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

can you help me please for solving this dophantine equation

$$x^2=y^p+1$$

and if you can give me a general method to studying such equation

$$x²=y^p+t$$

Thanks

Comment: Any condition on $p$? Is it supposed to be prime?

Comment: an integer $ p > 2 .. Thanks

Comment: See also [Mihăilescu's theorem and Pillai's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Pillai.27s_conjecture)

Comment: ok ,thank you Bartou ,so it's unsolved problem ..

Comment: Please tell us all the conditions. Are they $x,y\in\Bbb Z, p\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 2}$?

Comment: $x^2=y^p+1$ is fully solved. If $x,y\in\Bbb Z, p\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 2}$, then by Mihăilescu's theorem all the solutions are $(x,y,p)=(\pm 1, 0,p),(\pm 3,2,3),(0,-1,t)$ for odd $t\ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks , but this solutions dont works : we search the integers $x$ and $y$ for $t$ and $ p $fixed in $Z≥2$

Comment: @ABRAICHAyoub I clearly said I was talking about $x^2=y^p+1$, which is fully solved in $x,y\in\Bbb Z, p\in\Bbb Z_{\ge 2}$.

Comment: If $3\mid p$ and $-10^4\le t\le 10^4$, then $x^2=y^p+t$ can be solved using [Mordell equations](http://oeis.org/search?q=mordell&language=english&go=Search).

Comment: Ok , thank you , can you please give me any idea for studying this equation : $x^2 =y^p +2 $

Comment: @ABRAICHAyoub If $p$ is even, then $\left(x+y^{p/2}\right)\left(x-y^{p/2}\right)=2$ is easy to solve. If $3\mid p$, then the only solution is $(x,y,p)=(\pm 1,-1,3t)$ (here $t\in\Bbb Z^+$ is odd) (see [here](http://oeis.org/A081119)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Partial answer**

In general $x^2-1=y^p$. For $x$ even, $x-1,x+1$ are odd and relatively prime, and this it would mean $x-1=y_0^p$ and $x+1=y_1^p$. This is impossible unless $x=0$ and $p$ odd.

If $y$ is even, then $x$ is odd and $x-1$ and $x+1$ have only a factor of $2$ in common.

Thus, one of them must be of the form $2^{p-1}y_0^p$ and the other of the form $2y_1^p$ and $y_1$ odd. So you need to find $y_0$ and $y_1$ so that $$\left|2^{p-2}y_0^p-y_1^p\right|=1$$

This is definitely not possible of $p$ even, except when $y_1=1$ and $y_0=0$, since the left side is the difference of squares in that case.

Comment: Thank you so much , juste one more question : can you give me please a method for studying $ x^2-t=y^p , t > 1 $

Comment: I have no idea how, so no, I can't. Good luck!

Comment: If $p\ge 2$ is even, then all the integer solutions of $\left|2^{p-2}y_0^p-y_1^p\right|=1$ are $(y_0,y_1,p)=(\pm 1,0,2), (0,\pm 1,p)$.